# WordPress Manual Update SQL based on meta_value

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm writing a simple MySQL query to update a WordPress database. 
What I want to do is, anything with a post_meta (custom field) value of 3:RW, I want to set its post_parent to 4.

This is what I've written and have not run, as i want to validate before running:

```
UPDATE wp_posts, wp_postmeta SET wp_posts.post_parent='4' WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_value = '3:RW'
```

Does this seem acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the sql you wrote is not correct. Please try this following:

```
UPDATE wp_posts p JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON (p.ID = pm.post_id)
SET p.post_parent = 4
WHERE pm.meta_value = '3:RW';
```

FYI: wp_postmeta table must have page id